# Can I use `cp` in bash to watch files and folders and upon changes, copy them other to another folder?

Tags: linux, terminal, rsync, cp

**Update**

Okay, I've got `inotify` going, but I'm not sure how to pipe it into `cp`.

I can run `inotifywait -rm source/` and it will print to the terminal when changes happen to the file or new files are created and so forth.

Now I need to listen to when any change happens and just run `cp -u source/* destination/`

***How do I do this in bash in one line?***

**Old stuff below here...**

I'm using the cp command to copy files for my static site builder. I'm trying to also create a watch feature.

Can I use `cp` to somehow watch a file or folder full of files and other nested folders of files, and upon any saved changes to those files and folders copy them to a destination folder, effectively syncing one directory to another?

Or `rsync` or another command line tool?

Comment: I have not used it, but you may be interested in [`inotifywait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html).

Comment: @jxh Thanks! Hm... how do I combine inotify with cp?

Comment: The man page has examples near the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
inotifywait -rm -e CLOSE_WRITE --format "%w" source | stdbuf -o0 sed 's@/$@@' | xargs -n1 -I{} rsync -Rva {} destination
```

Using inotify to watch for close_write events (rather than **all** or **modify**), only outputting the directory in which the change occurred, trimming the trailing slash and feeding that to rsync (telling it to preserver the full path and not use compression).

Comment: Dam, I wish I was better at bash. This is almost what I need. It's cp I want to use rather than rsync. That way i can use the -u flag and forgo making copies if there aren't changes.

Comment: @Costa - that's the whole purpose of `rsync` ... it only syncs changes.

Comment: Right well, the code you have above copies everything every time.

Comment: Hmm... seems to work now actually. I must be doing something wrong. Doesn't sync over deletes. I'm going to adjust it a bit more. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To get deletions across use the additional flag `--delete` ... `rsync -Rva --delete  {} destination`

Comment: Great, thanks! That's what I did : ) Yay, I'm learning!

Comment: Hm... wondering if I can simplify what we've got. Also, the first time it runs, it creates the directory, and then subsequent times it runs it does not create the directory even though I've deleted it.

Comment: Also, I added events, since I'm trying to watch for all kinds of changes, like creating a new subdirectory, or deleting a directory, or deleting a file, and so on. I truly want to watch and copy all changes.

Comment: That won't be possible with a one-liner. These tools (inotifywatch/inotifywait) scan the directory tree ONCE  when you start them with a "recursive flag". Subsequently created directories will no be monitored for changes ... And you'd also have to be more specific with  the "it does not create the directory even though I've deleted it." ... that tells me very little about what might be going on.

Comment: Hmm... The line I'm using is this... `inotifywait -rm -e modify,attrib,close_write,move,create,delete --format \"%w\" source/ | stdbuf -o0 sed 's@/$@@' | xargs -n1 -I{} rsync -Rva --delete {} destination/` The -m flag on inotifywait will monitor the directly, so it continues to run. Not sure what you mean by ONCE. And currently, that line will detect new sub-directories, file deletions and such, and copies them over. So, it's working. Curiously, when I ran it the first time... 'destination/destination' showed up as a directly.

Comment: It will monitor for newly created directories within the initially present directory structure. It won't monitor for files/directories that then get created within the new directories, though, that would require you to restart the process. One possible work-around would be to create a script proper and run that as a service, with the option to terminate itself if a directory gets created and have it restarted via a systemd unit file.